# android MyLocationOverlay stop GPS onPause

Tags: android, memory-management, gps

Im using MyLocationOverlay to get my location. But i would like to stop GPS onPause and resume it onResume. How can i do that ?

I know for LocationManager is method removeUpdates...

```
final MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay); 

locButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
        });{

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your activity that is pausing:

```
@Override public void onPause() {
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    super.onPause();
}
@Override public void onResume() {
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    super.onResume();
}
```

but I haven't compiled that. From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the [`MyLocationOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay) object when you create it and simply use the `enableMyLocation()` and `disableMylocation()` methods in respectively `onResume()` and `onPause()`. Depending on how you set up your code, you may want to do a `null` check before calling anything on the overlay.